# Dompdf is not printing the table with posted php form

Tags: php, html, dompdf

When I try to print the table in the file_html.php it prints the static table with some error(that's a different question). However, when the php tags for the posted data are included in the file with the post variables, the pdf generated displays nothing at all except for the anchor tag which is at the bottom of the page.

Here is the index.php :-

```
            require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
            require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php");
            spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

            function pdf_create($html, $filename, $paper, $orientation, $stream=TRUE)
                {
                    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
                    $dompdf->set_paper($paper,$orientation);
                    $dompdf->load_html_file('http://localhost/pdf/file_html.php');
                    $dompdf->render();
                    $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
                }
                $filename = 'billofsale';
                $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
                $html = file_get_contents('http://localhost/pdf/file_html.php'); 
                pdf_create($html,$filename,'A4','portrait');
```

And here is the file_html.php which consists the form with the post variable. Note : when the php with the post is removed the table prints out in the pdf.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
            <style type="text/css">
            table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              border: 0;
              font-size: 100%;
              font: inherit;

            }
            table {
              border-collapse: collapse;
              border-spacing: 0;
              width:100%;
            }
            body{
                font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
            }

            th{
                text-align: center;
                border: 3px solid #ccd;
            }
            td{
                padding: 0.25rem;
                text-align: left;
                border: 2px solid #ccc;
            }

            tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
                background: #eee;
            }
            tbody:before, thead:after { display: none; }


            </style>
            </head>

            <body>

            <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                ?>
            <p>
            <table>
                <thead><th colspan="2">Purchaser's Information</th></thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Purchaser's Name :  <?php echo $_POST['pname']; ?></td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">Purchaser's Address : <?php echo $_POST['padd']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>City/Town : <?php echo $_POST['pcity']; ?> </td>
                        <td>Province : <?php echo $_POST['ppro']; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Postal Code :<?php echo $_POST['ppcode']; ?></td>
                        <td>Home Tel No :<?php echo $_POST['ptelno']; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Business Tel :<?php echo $_POST['pbtel']; ?></td>
                        <td>Email :<?php echo $_POST['pemail']; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Driver License : <?php echo $_POST['pdriverlic']; ?></td>
                        <td>Expiry Date :<?php echo $_POST['pdriverexp']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            </p>    
            <?php
                }   
            ?>
            <a href="index.php">Print </a>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: May *it is related* to PHP errors? Maybe DomPDF can't parse invalid HTML structure caused by errors?

Comment: but there are no errors in php or in html.

Comment: **it prints the static table with some error**

Comment: Can you point me out the error , its not a php error or html error..its something to do with rendering...

Comment: FYI, you don't need the line that reads `require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php");`. This is included as part of the setup process by dompdf_config.inc.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading file_html.php using `$dompdf->load_html_file('http://localhost/pdf/file_html.php');`. This method is like starting a new browser request using the GET method. Any variables set during the current PHP process are not passed through. This means the `$_POST` array is empty.

There are a few ways of addressing the issue, but since your table relies on data from the `$_POST` array I'd suggest using output buffering. You can render the content within index.php, capture the output, and feed it to dompdf.

Using your original sample as a starting point ...

```
<?php
ob_start();
require 'file_html.php'
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper('a4','portrait');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('billofsale.pdf');
?>
```

Now when you POST to index.php the $_POST array will be available to file_html.php.

Comment: 1.The submit is on another page, it was posting the data so I did not put that file here.

Comment: The issue is that not only does the `$_POST` array come blank but also the html does not render. The pdf only displays the `a` tag

Comment: When I remove the php tags from file_html.php, the html form renders with the first table row breaking out of sequence.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up #1. My main point still holds, however. Since you're loading the file in a second call using load_html_file the POST variables will not flow through to index.php. The majority of your HTML content is inside a conditional against the $_POST array, so it will never render.

Comment: I modified the answer to use another option that should work better for you.

Comment: Let me try it out, because that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Firstly, I tried to use the above code in replace of what I had in index.php so it return with error in `$html`.Secondly, I tried to echo the `$html` and it just has the `a` tag in it.